# DEM data to Excel using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I have downloaded a DEM from digmap and have opened it in ArcMap.

I now want to transfer elevations from each gridsquare into excel to be used in a water routing model.

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use grid to ASCII. This will give you a space separated array. You will have to strip off the header information.

Answer (score 2):

You could export your DEM to GRIDASCII. The output will be a matrix with the first lines indicating some image parameters and then the data. [GridAscii format](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=ESRI%20ASCII%20Raster%20format).

Or you could generate a bunch of vector points for each gridsquare and the use the extract to point tool to get a table with the DEM value for each gridsquare